# How to load a STL vector with a constant

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a `vector<double>` that has already been resized to be 1200, what is the best way to load that vector with the same value in each slot? The value is not known at compile time.

Right now I just use a loop through all 1200 slots and set each slot equal to the value. I was wondering if this was the best way to do this.

Comment: [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Comment: When you resize, you can provide an initial value for new elements as the second argument. When you initialize a vector, you can also provide an initial value to use for each element. If you are resizing before knowing the initial value, could you instead delay that resize until you have this information?

Comment: I do the resize way beforehand, all my vectors are 1200 in size. I resize them all in one function.  But they are loaded with data in different ways, this is only one example. And of course the value to load is not the same for each vector... I was just hoping for a more concise way to load the vector.

Comment: The best method would be to look up your platform's processor instruction set and see if it has an instruction to set a block of memory to the value in a register.  The next best would be to perform the operation in parallel.  Otherwise, the method is insignificant (`std::fill` or `for` loop).  You could try "loop unrolling" so that you write a block in each iteration (such as 12 cells).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `std::fill` should perform whatever optimizations are available on the platform

Comment: @M.M Not necessarily.  The `std::fill` would be optimized for the general case.  The OP may want to optimize for this specific case, as there could be some benefits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::vector` constructor

> `explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
>                    const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());`

next way

```
vector<double> myVector;
double value = 1.;
myVector = vector<double>(1200, value);
```

alternative is `std::fill`, which will avoid memory allocation

```
std::fill(begin(myVector), end(myVector), value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *loop unrolling*:

```
std::vector<double> my_vector(1200);
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i += 4)
{
    my_vector[i + 0] = value;
    my_vector[i + 1] = value;
    my_vector[i + 2] = value;
    my_vector[i + 3] = value;
}
```

I suggest playing around with the number of assignments in the loop.  The idea here is to reduce the overhead of incrementing and branching (do more data operations).

Comment: The compiler should do this if optimization is enabled and it would be beneficial on the platform